# Why is scanned PDF size varies with scanners?

Tags: pdf, resolution, scanning, all-in-one

I have a Samsung SCX 4623 FW all in one and a Canon multifunction at work. I observed that the PDF files generated after scanning documents is quite different.

The PDF generated by SCX 4623 FW is 10 times larger in most cases. The software used is SmarThru Office 4 on the Samsung printer. With Canon printer it is SmartScan.

I checked the page size, resolution and color depth to match. I thought that after matching these parameters, the file size should be similar. What could be causing the file size to be so large?

Comment: I would be surprised if they were the same, there is no "standard" resolution that companies go by when exporting your scanned document to you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you matched resolution (dpi) and color depth what is left to check is PDF Compression.

The software that came with my Canon flatbed scanners gives me the choice between "Standard" and "High" PDF Compression. Other scan software might give you more fine-grained control over PDF Compression (e.g. Adobe Acrobat). Apart from the level of compression there are also different compression algorithms. But usually only more advanced scan software offers the possibility to choose the compression algorithm (e.g. Adobe Acrobat).

So look for the section in your scan programs where you choose the file type (jpg, pdf, tiff, etc.) for your scans. Somewhere there should be the option to choose compression.